# WSO2-AM Transform Request, Response

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to manipulate the content of requests and responses somehow.

1) Passing just relevant parameters

```
API Request : ?par1=val1&par2=val2
BackEnd Request : ?par1=val1
```

2) Passing API Header parameters as Query-string parameters

```
API Request : "x-uuid : 034060c8-f2e0-4f38-ad83-37c1fbd5e239"
BackEnd Request : ?uuid=034060c8-f2e0-4f38-ad83-37c1fbd5e239
```

3) Construct a response including more BackEnd requests and responses

```
BackEnd response1 : { par1:val1 }
BackEnd response2 : { par2:val2 }
API Response : { par1:val1, par2:val2 }
```

4) Data conversion

```
string <-> number, etc...
```

How can I do it? Is there any visual tool for it in WSO2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by using WSO2 ESB product [1]. Simply you can send your request to a proxy created within the ESB, do the transformation and send respond back to your endpoint once the transformation is done. You can do these validations using ESB mediators [2]. If you need a visual tool to create the proxy service,sequences and mediators, you can use WSO2 developer studio [3].

Also, you can do the same implementation using API-Manager Custom Mediation Sequences explained at [8].

Please find more information below to give you a high level idea.

1) Passing just relevant parameters:-
You can use the Script mediator to achive this by writing your own javascript and use regex maipulation to filter out what you need [4].

2) Passing API Header parameters as Query-string parameters
You can manipulate the header values using the Header mediator [5].

3) Construct a response including more BackEnd requests and responses:-

Not quite sure about the exact requirement here. But If you look at the iterate mediator [6] and aggregate mediator [7] it might help you to get an idea about how you might wanna achieve this.

4) Data conversion

I think this depends on the what you are trying to achive by doing the conversion. If you simply want to convert a value then you can do this by using javascript within a script mediator.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/WSO2+Enterprise+Service+Bus+Documentation

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Mediators

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/Creating+ESB+Artifacts

[4] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Script+Mediator

[5] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Header+Mediator

[6] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Iterate+Mediator

[7] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Aggregate+Mediator

[8]  https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Change+the+Default+Mediation+Flow+of+API+Requests

Hope this answer helped you to get an idea.

Cheers, 
Pubudu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.